# Passing data from ReactJS form to Rails API causes app to crash

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, forms, asynchronous

As a premise, this is the first time I have create a web application using React for the frontend and Rails as a backend, so I apologize in advance for any huge mistakes. I tried searching for the same problem I did not find any solutions yet.

**THE ISSUE:**

I have a table with employees data. To add a new employee I am collecting data from a form in React and I am making a POST request to the Rails API. After the data are successfully saved in the backend I want the app to re-render the table with the new added employee.
Now, the data are successfully transferred from React to the API and are correctly saved in the backend, however after the data are saved, everything crashes and the table is not re-rendered except after some time (<1 min).

**THE CODE:**

This is the employees controller (I'm posting just the create function for simplicity):

```
#employees_controller.rb

class Api::V1::EmployeesController < ApplicationController

# POST /employees
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_param)

    if @employee.save!
      render json: @employee, status: :created, location: api_v1_employees_path(@employee)
    else
      render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessed_entity
    end
  end

 private

  def employee_param
    params.require(:employee).permit(:fullname, :email, :phone_number, :company, :is_admin)
  end

end
```

I think it works fine, as the data are successfully saved in the right place and I can see them being displayed in the index.

This is the React table that displays the employees data:

```
// DataTable.js
// DataTable component (shows the employees data)
import React from "react";

import {
  TableContainer,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
} from "@mui/material";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const StyledTableHeaderCell = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "#232020",
    fontSize: "12px",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    lineHeight: "150%",
    fontFamily: "Poppins",
  },
})(TableCell);

const StyledTableCell = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "#232020",
    fontSize: "12px",
    lineHeight: "150%",
    fontFamily: "Poppins",
  },
})(TableCell);

function DataTable({ header, employeesData }) {
  console.log(typeof employeesData);
  console.log(employeesData);
  return (
    <TableContainer
      sx={{
        maxHeight: 440,
        minWidth: 650,
        overflow: "auto",
        width: "95%",
        marginTop: "37px",
        borderRadius: "10px",
        border: "1px solid #E6EDFF",
      }}
    >
      <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
        <TableHead sx={{ display: "table-header-group" }}>
          <TableRow>
            {header.map((field, idx) => {
              return { idx } === 0 ? (
                <StyledTableHeaderCell key={idx}>{field}</StyledTableHeaderCell>
              ) : (
                <StyledTableHeaderCell align="right" key={idx}>
                  {field}
                </StyledTableHeaderCell>
              );
            })}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>

        <TableBody>
          {employeesData.map((employee, idx) => {
            return (
              <TableRow
                key={idx}
                sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
              >
                <StyledTableHeaderCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {employee.fullname}
                </StyledTableHeaderCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">
                  {employee.company}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">
                  {employee.email}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">
                  {employee.phone_number}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">
                  {employee.is_admin ? "Admin" : "Tecnico"}
                </StyledTableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

export default DataTable;
```

where the Object employeeData is passed as a prop from this component:

```
// Employees.js
// Employees index

import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import DataTable from "../shared/DataTable";
import BtnContainer from "../components/buttonsdiv";

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/employees";

function getAPIData(params) {
  return axios.get(API_URL).then((response) => response.data);
}

function EmployeesPage() {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    getAPIData().then((items) => {
      if (mounted) {
        setEmployees(items);
      }
    });
    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

  // Callback function to receive data from the child component
  const handleFormSubmit = (data) => {
    setEmployees((prev) => ({ ...prev, data }));
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      // the component BtnContainer contains the button that triggers the form that gets the employee data and the form itself
          <BtnContainer
            apiURL={API_URL}
            text="Aggiungi impiegato"
            onFormSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
            formTitle="Aggiungi nuovo impiegato"
          />
          {employees === undefined ? (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          ) : (
            // DataTable is the table that displays the employees data
            <DataTable
              header={["Nome", "Società", "Email", "Telefono", "Ruolo"]}
              employeesData={employees}
            />
          )}

    </Box>
  );
}

export default EmployeesPage;
```

**MY HYPOTHESIS AND WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

I thought the problem was the fact that once I sent the data to the API and re-render the page, the employees object still hasn't been filled with the data yet, so it's undefined. I tried putting a conditional that if the object is undefined instead of the table it shows a loading thingy, but it's not working. So I am a bit lost :,)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by substituting this line

```
setEmployees((prev) => ({ ...prev, data }));
```

with this

```
setEmployees((prev) => [...prev, data]);
```

in the Employees.js file.